# How to print all possible combinations in string using itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am studying Python personally these days.
I have a question about python code.

```py
A = "I " + (can/cannot) + " fly"
B = "I am " + (13/15) + " years old"
```

In theses cases, **variable `A`** can select two options, `'can'` or `'cannot'`.
Also, **variable `B`** can select two options, `13` or `15`.
I don't want to use these options myself.
I don't know how to select two options automatically.

If it can be automatically, I want to use `itertools` module.
I want result using "combinations" to do this.

```py
C = [(I can fly I am 13 years old) , (I can fly I am 15 years old) , (I cannot fly I am 13 years old) , (I cannot fly I am 15 years old)]
```

If anyone who can help me with this code, please help.

Comment: What have you tried doing to solve this problem?

Comment: `for a, b in itertools.product(a_options, b_options): ...`

Answer (score 3):

First, you would like to find all the combinations of (can/cannot) and (13/15).

To do this you can use:

```
import itertools
can_or_cannot = ['can', 'cannot']
age = [13, 15]
list(itertools.product(can_or_cannot, age))

Out[13]: [('can', 13), ('can', 15), ('cannot', 13), ('cannot', 15)]
```

Now you can use list comprehension:

```
C = [f"I {can_or_cannot} fly I am {age} years old" for (can_or_cannot, age) in list(itertools.product(can_or_cannot, age))]


Out[15]: 
['I can fly I am 13 years old',
 'I can fly I am 15 years old',
 'I cannot fly I am 13 years old',
 'I cannot fly I am 15 years old']
```

Or, as suggested by @Olvin Roght, you can use a template and `starmap`:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

template = 'I {} fly I am {} years old'
result = list(starmap(template.format, product(can_or_cannot, age)))
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.

Comment: @theletz, you can define `template = "I {} fly I am {} years old"` and then do `list(itertools.starmap(template.format, itertools.product(can_or_cannot, age)))`.

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, @theletz decided to not include my recommendation into his answer, so I'll post it here:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

can_or_cannot = ['can', 'cannot']
age = [13, 15]
template = 'I {} fly I am {} years old'

result = list(starmap(template.format, product(can_or_cannot, age)))
```

How does it work?

1. We use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get cartesian product of two lists;
2. Result of previous action we redirect directly to [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), which execute [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and pass unpacked pair as function arguments.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
fly = ["can","cannot"]
lst = []
for i in fly:
    A = "I " + i + " fly"
    for j in [13,15]:
        B = " I am " + str(j) + " years old"
        lst.append((A+B))
print(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.

Comment: Even if it works, it's very bad solution. Why do you use list instead of tuple? Why do you not use string formatting? Why do you need 2 pairs of parentheses in `append()`? Have you ever read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)?