# python how to make sequential combinations

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a question.
I've tried it like an example below.

```
import itertools

options = ['A', 'B', 'C']

true_or_false = ['true', 'false']

result1 = [f"{option} is " for option in options]
```

The results are as follows.

```
print(result1)
['A is ', 'B is ', 'C is ']
```

I want to use "true_or_false" to produce a result2 like this.

```
('A is true' 'B is true' 'C is true')
('A is true' 'B is true' 'C is false')
('A is true' 'B is false' 'C is true')
('A is true' 'B is false' 'C is false')
('A is false' 'B is true' 'C is true')
('A is false' 'B is true' 'C is false')
('A is false' 'B is false' 'C is true')
('A is false' 'B is false' 'C is false')
```

I think it is using "combinations," but it's not working.

Comment: If I understood well, you can simply tackle this problem w/ nested loops. See my answer below. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your question is literally the same as previous. Check my answer on previous question and apply it here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print all possible combinations in string using itertools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162536/how-to-print-all-possible-combinations-in-string-using-itertools)

Comment: @OlvinRoght  I know that similar to the previous my question. I am wandering because it is the first time I have studied program language.

Answer (score 2):

Simple nested loops can output what you need

```
result2 = []
true_or_false = ['true','false']
for a in true_or_false:
    for b in true_or_false:
        for c in true_or_false:
            result2.append(('A is ' + a, 'B is ' + b, 'C is ' + c))
```

And `result2` will be a list of tuples:

```
[('A is true', 'B is true', 'C is true'),
 ('A is true', 'B is true', 'C is false'),
 ('A is true', 'B is false', 'C is true'),
 ('A is true', 'B is false', 'C is false'),
 ('A is false', 'B is true', 'C is true'),
 ('A is false', 'B is true', 'C is false'),
 ('A is false', 'B is false', 'C is true'),
 ('A is false', 'B is false', 'C is false')]
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me another way I didn't think of. @floatingpurr

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with the `repeat` argument, and `zip`:

```py
>>> [ tuple(opt + ' is ' + val for opt, val in zip(options, values))
...   for values in itertools.product(true_or_false, repeat=len(options)) ]
[('A is true', 'B is true', 'C is true'),
 ('A is true', 'B is true', 'C is false'),
 ('A is true', 'B is false', 'C is true'),
 ('A is true', 'B is false', 'C is false'),
 ('A is false', 'B is true', 'C is true'),
 ('A is false', 'B is true', 'C is false'),
 ('A is false', 'B is false', 'C is true'),
 ('A is false', 'B is false', 'C is false')]
```

Comment: The way I imagined it was, I didn't think about "zip" and "repeat." Thanks. @kaya3

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something concise.

```
import pprint

options = ['A', 'B', 'C']
true_or_false = ['true', 'false']

result2 = []
[result2.append(('A is ' + a, 'B is ' + b, 'C is ' + c)) for a in true_or_false for b in true_or_false for c in
 true_or_false]

pprint.pprint(result2)
```

Output :

```
[('A is true', 'B is true', 'C is true')
 ('A is true', 'B is true', 'C is false'),
 ('A is true', 'B is false', 'C is true'),
 ('A is true', 'B is false', 'C is false'),
 ('A is false', 'B is true', 'C is true'),
 ('A is false', 'B is true', 'C is false'),
 ('A is false', 'B is false', 'C is true'),
 ('A is false', 'B is false', 'C is false')]
```

Comment: It's a little different than I thought, but thank you.